# How do to set a session from a hidden field?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an option to let a person checkout on my page as a guest without logging in. The `controller` will redirect all checkout submits as follows:

- If the user is logged in (check session) `session->userdata`. If they are logged in -> `redirect('checkout_process')`
- If the user is not logged in -> `redirect('login')`

On the login page their is a button that says `checkout as guest` How do I pass a session to let the user checkout as a guest without forcing them to login when they click this button?

Comment: when the user log in as guest you can start a session and set a variable like $_SESSION['guest'] = 1;

Comment: If there is a button it isn't a hidden field right?  What is the action of the form that the button lives in?  Does it handle the redirects in your login controller?

Comment: I resolved this issue in the controller. I don't need to set a session. I just need to route to proper checkout `view` based on `if` session is set. Thanks anyway